# c++ dll, how to write to a double value of a pointer in memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dll, double

I'm facing this problem with trying to write to a pointer to a double in a memory process when I do dll injection.

Here is my class:

```
class SpeedHack : public MasterClass {
    private:
        SpeedHack() {};
        struct Speed { double speed; };
    public:
        Speed* getAddy()
        {
            return (Speed*)(address);
        }
        bool isSpeedAtkon = false;

        void writeMem()
        {

            getAddy()->speed = 3.1;

        }
        static SpeedHack& get()
        {
            static SpeedHack instance;
            return instance;
        }
    };

//address is 0x767650 and value is a double 0.300000
```

I have also other classes like it and all other work, but I never have double in the structure (only in this class)

The application crashes onceIi try to call writeMemory() method... Other structs from other classes always work even if they are more complex...

logging this : Logger::log("%f", SpeedHack::get().getAddy()->speed); returns me 0.300000 as expected and also logging the address returns me the correct one...

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong... (app crashes once I try to change double value at this address)... does someone know how I could fix it?

Comment: I assume that by "double pointer" you actually mean a pointer *to* a `double` (and not e.g. `sometype **`)?

Comment: yes sorry im not english native speaker

Comment: *How* does the program crash? Because you don't have write access to the value, or because 3.1 is an incorrect value? Or something else?

Comment: i certainly dont have write access... but when i try whit a memory editor, it works well (cheat engine) . this program said me that the address is writable, and i tried to change to 3.1 from cheat engine it also works

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks Bo persson i solved it with this piece of code... i grabbed it from internet, but i dont know all of it is needed :

```
void doSpeedAtk()
        {
            DWORD OldProtection;
            VirtualProtect((LPVOID)address, 4, PAGE_READWRITE, &OldProtection);
            getAddy()->speed = 3.1;
            VirtualProtect((LPVOID)address, 4, PAGE_READWRITE, &OldProtection);
        }
```

Comment: Probably want to write back to `OldProtection` rather than readwrite on the second value.

Comment: Your second VirtualProtect should have `OldProtection` where it says `PAGE_READWRITE` to set it back to what it was - or just leave it as is and don't have the second line at all.